# GoogleMap Support Fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-support-library

I have a project that uses the GoogleMaps API, and the support library for Fragments. I have a working map in one activity already, so I know that the API and library are all set up right. I am trying to add a map in a fragment as part of a new activity.

The activity extends an android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, and the xml file contains:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

But when I run I get the error:

```
01-20 11:58:31.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    at com.yedidyak.gpsalarm.AddAlarm.onCreate(AddAlarm.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

All the information I can find about this error is about not having the google-play-lib properly installed both as a jar and an imported module, but I have that done - and a working map in another activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference google play services library instead of adding jar and map_attrs.xml (and other files, like strings.xml) to your project.

If you do, you also might have deleted res/values/map_attrs.xml by accident.